# How can I use HttpClient in my .NET Framework 4.5 app/site?

Tags: asp.net, http, razor, asp.net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

Based on the answer here: [How can I retrieve and parse just the html returned from an URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470458/how-can-i-retrieve-and-parse-just-the-html-returned-from-an-url)

...I'm trying to begin by adding code based on that found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

...namely by adding this to \App_Code\Functions.cshtml:

```
@functions
{
    public static string GetUrlHtml(string dynamicUrl)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string body = await client.GetStringAsync(dynamicUrl);
    // parse it using HTML Agility Pack? (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
    }
}
```

HttpClient is not recognized, and does not afford a "resolve" context menu item. Intellisense does not offer me a "Http" after entering:

```
@using System.Net.
```

Is HttpClient really unavailable to me? If so, what can I have as a consolation prize? Is my best option to use WebClient like so:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string body = wc.DownloadString(dynamicUrl);
// parse it with html agility pack
```

...or, as shown at https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx#postadlink, I can use the webGet class from the HTML Agility Pack:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load(dynamicUrl);
```

Does anybody have any supportable opinions on which option is the best?

Comment: Are you trying to do a HTTP request from Razor view? Why?

Comment: Check the References, do you have `System.Net.Http` there?

Comment: Why not? I like Razor.

Comment: Well, it is a view. Such logic should be in model or controller.

Comment: I'm not using MVC; this code is in a functions cshtml file. MVC is overkill for this site, I think. Too abstract.

Comment: The whole MVC and EF  extravaganza, as well as some of the test harnass stuff, sometimes strikes me as a bunch of smoke and mirrors. I'm not saying that it's the work of charlatans, or that it doesn't work, or doesn't have its place at times, but oftentimes those layers upon layers of abstraction add levels of complexity that are anathema to clarity - and, thus, productivity.

Comment: The best thing about approaches like MVC (or Agile, UnitTesting, etc) is that they do not need defense. In time, ignoring those will automatically bite you. But in the meantime, have you checked that `System.Net.Http` is referenced?

Comment: What do you mean by referenced? Entering System.Net. didn't bring up Http as a possibility to be "resolved".

Comment: What assembly would need to be added? I very rarely have to do that; normally it's just adding a "using" clause, which Intellisense prompts me to do.

Comment: Those "approaches" often feel like attempts to be as tricky as possible, somewhat akin to the Enron school of accounting. I'm not saying they don't have their place, just that many projects could do without all the foofaraw, and in fact be more grokkable and more quickly completed without them. Woody Allen doesn't need a shirt tailor-made for Hulk Hogan.

Comment: _What assembly would need to be added?_ `System.Net.Http.dll`?
_Those "approaches" often feel like attempts to be as tricky as possible_ It is very unspecific so hard to prove or disprove. The reason why MVC exists is because development is often about managing complexity that is already here (from business, infrastructure, security, etc). Given that complexity MVC and other approaches are a fair investment.

Comment: Yes, I agree; I'm saying many projects are *not* that complex and are dragged down rather than assisted by such.

Comment: See my answer below. Add to the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this nuget package and it will add the appropriate references http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.0.20710.0

Comment: I thought .NET 4.5 includes this dll directly?

Answer (score 5):

Wrong answer is the accepted one.

This is the correct one:

Add to the config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But the `<assemblies>` tag need to be inside the `<compilation>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have an assembly reference to `System.Net.Http`.

Comment: What I can do in the .cshtml file is add:

@using System.Net.

...but "Http" is not one of the values Intellisense then offers. And there is no "References" subfolder in this web site project (Razor 2) like there is in a "normal" or desktop app, so I don't know how to add System.Net.Http. Actually, I'm going to try Darrel Miller's suggestion.